# how to connet wired network in fedora/ubuntu via ISP (username and password)?

Tags: linux, connection, modem, broadband, adsl

I have tried to connect wired network connection using modem of ISP provider in Linux  but could not see the option for Ethernet/Broadband in network connection.
While i choose add (+) option, there has been list of

> - VPN
> - Bridge
> - Bond
> - VLAN

I am ex-window user where i setup the internet connection using setup new network or connection using broadband/Adsl option in window network connection without router(only use modem provided by ISP provider).

Comment: Do you know if your ISP uses PPPOE to create a connection (typical with DSL connections)?

Comment: yes, it use pppoe connection

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can use the program `pppoeconf` (available through `apt-get`) which will walk you through inputting the settings necessary to establish a pppoe connection through your ISP. More documentation on this procedure is available for Ubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE.

Comment: This does not help me any more . I even download package ppoe file and try to install but it say error like this ** This software come from third party and may contain non-free component ** What shall i do?